# 3 people roll a fair dice once. What is the probability that the highest value rolled is not rolled by more than one person?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Question as above. Wanted to consider the cases of them doing the rolls after each other, but didn't seem to be right

Comment: Any own thought on the topic?

Comment: I tried saying ''Let person A roll 1'' then there was a $5/6$ chance that B rolled a number bigger than that, and then to consider "If B rolled a 1, there is a $5/6$ chance C didn't roll a 1 so that is that part sorted. But I got lost when there was a probability that B & C rolled the highest

Comment: I gave some hints in an answer, I usually try not to completely answer questions here (where is the fun in that?) so please read it and if you have more questions you are free to ask them

Comment: Thanks. So would you recommend doing it by just considering every case?

Comment: not exactly, but you got some answers which are even better than mine ;)

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa using your method, obviously there are 6 ways in which all 3 numbers are equal. But how do you calculate how many of which are when 2 rolled the highest? If the 2 highest are 6, then there are 5 other options in which the last number could be, and 3 ways to arrange these numbers so that would be 15 just for when 2 6's are rolled, 12 when 2 5's are rolled etc. Then as theres 216 possible combinations 216-6 (all the same) -15-12-9-6-3= 165

Comment: Think as follows: when the highest is $6$ then there are $5$ possibilites for the third person, namely $\{1,2,3,4,5 \}$ this gives $5$ outcomes. If $5$ is the highest, bby the same logic you get $4$ outcomes and so on. This gives $15$ outcomes. Now, we havent yet talked about the distribution of these between the players. For each case there are $3$ since you can have $(6,6,5),(6,5,6),(5,6,6)$ so you have to multiply $15$ by $3$. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I understand the logic as it is what I've used, but surely you multiply 5 by 3, not 15, as there are 5 possiblities which can fill the gap in (6,6,$x$), and 3 organisations of 6,6 and $x$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89991/discussion-between-vinyl-coat-jawa-and-anouser1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS:

The statement "the highest value rolled is not rolled by more than one person" can be translated as "there is a definite winner".

To find the probability we have to find all possible outcomes then find the outcomes that are *preferable* so to say.

We can use the complement event to find the latter

$$
\#\text{every outcome}-\#\text{when two people rolled the highest}-\#\text{all rolled the same}
$$

where $\#$ stands for "number of".

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the highest number rolled is $k$.  There are $3$ ways to choose the person who rolls $k$.  There are then $(k-1)^2$ possibilities for the rolls of the other two people.  What are the possible values of $k?$  What is the size of the sample space?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

How many elements $(a,b,c)$ of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^3$ have the property that one of the coordinates exceeds the other two?

If e.g. $\max(a,b,c)=3$ then such an element must have one of the looks $(3,\cdot,\cdot)$, $(\cdot,3,\cdot)$, $(\cdot,\cdot,3)$ where the dots must take values in $\{1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $6^3=216$ equiprobable outcomes $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in all. We have to count the number of outcomes with a single maximal toss. Such an outcome can happen when the maximal toss is $r\in\{2,3,4,5,6\}$. Given $r$, there are three persons that can achieve it, and the other two persons  only obtain a result in $\{1,2,\ldots, r-1\}$. It follows that there are
$$\sum_{r=2}^6 3 (r-1)^2=3(1+4+9+16+25)=165$$ 
outcomes satisfying the given condition. The probability $p$ of the desired event therefore is given by
$$p={165\over216}={55\over72}\ .$$

Comment: An outcome can happen when r=2, as the other 2 could have rolled a 1