# Probability that no decision is reached in the first n trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, dice

Three siblings cannot agree which TV programme to watch. They decide that each of them rolls a fair die and that the person with the highest number gets to choose the TV programme. If two or more persons get the highest number (e.g. numbers on dice are (5, 5, 2) or (4, 4, 4)) then they roll the dice again.

1) Let n ∈ N be fixed. How do I compute the probability that no decision is reached in the first n trials?

2) Let n ∈ N. How do I compute the probability that, if the decision is reached in the n trial, in at least one trial before the decision was reached all the scores were the same.

Could anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Binomial distribution for the first one but nothing for the second one, can't think of anything..

Comment: Try to search for geometric distribution ;)

Comment: For the second one, a quick hint would be to look at the probability of getting no events where all scores are the same in $n-1$ tries given that all scores come from the set of undecidable options

Comment: It would be sensible to start by calculating (a) the probability in a single trial that not decision is made and (b) the probability in a single trial all values are the same.  Incidentally, in your $5,5,2$ example, how many people throw again, two or three?

Comment: @Henry 3 people throw

Comment: I've calculated the probability of P(no decision is made)= 1-P(decision is made)=1-(105/216)=111/216 (if this is correct)

Comment: @ThePoorJew For the first problem. The first sibling rolls a specific number. The probability is  $\frac16$. The probability that the second sibling rolls an equal number is $\frac16$. The probability that the second sibling rolls a different number is $\frac56$. The sequence is $XXY$.  Since $X$ can be a number from $1-6$ we have to multiply the product by $6$.

Comment: @ThePoorJew (continued) And we can arrange $XXY$ in 3 ways. Therefore the probability rolling exaclty two equal numbers is reached in one round is $3\cdot 6\cdot \frac16\cdot \frac16\cdot \frac56=\frac{15}{36}=\frac5{12}$ Comprehensible? What is the probability that all three siblings roll the same number?

Comment: @ThePoorJew By the way if you use converse probability then the calculation is $1-6\cdot \frac16\cdot \frac56\cdot \frac46=1-\frac{20}{36}=\frac{16}{36}=\frac49$

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3120512/627720) for the probability that a decision is made in a single trial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can approach the problem geometrically.

Each triple toss $\left( {x_{\,1} ,x_{\,2} ,x_{\,3} } \right)$ corresponds to an integral point
in a cube with side $[1,6]$: wlog we can take the die to be numbered $0,1,\cdots , 5$, 
being more convenient to place the cube with one vertex at the origin.
Let's make it general and take a cube with side $[0,r]$.
Being the die fair, all the $\left({r+1} \right)^3$ points are equi-probable.

Consider the region made by the points points which obey to
$$
{0 \le x_{\,1}  < x_{\,2}  < x_{\,3}  \le r}
$$
The *integral volume* of such a region is clearly
$$
\binom{r+1}{3}
$$
(choose three values from the $r+1$, and arrange in order).
There are six of such regions, corresponding to the permutations of the $x_k$.

The diagonal of the cube instead,  $x_1=x_2=x_3$,  has a *volume* of $r+1$.

Let's make it even more general, in the case of $m$ siblings, note that
the expansion of the binomial in terms of [Falling Factorials][1] via the 
Stirling N. of 2nd kind
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,m}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {
 \left\{ \matrix{ m \cr  k \cr}  \right\}\left( {r + 1} \right)^{\underline {\,k\,} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\
  underbrace {\left( {k!\left\{ \matrix{m \cr   k \cr}  \right\}} \right)}_{N.}
\underbrace {\left( \matrix{  r + 1 \cr   k \cr}  \right)}_{Vol.}}  \cr} 
$$
represents the splitting of the cube into the regions
$$
\left[ {x_{\,1}  < x_{\,2}  <  \cdots  < x_{\,m} } \right],\left[ {x_{\,1}  = x_{\,2}  <  \cdots  < x_{\,m} } \right], \cdots ,
\left[ {x_{\,1}  = x_{\,2}  =  \cdots  = x_{\,m} } \right]
$$
and in the formula above $k$ represents the number of $<$ signs + 1.
This can be demonstrated resorting to the meaning of the Stirling N. 2nd kind$\left\{ \matrix{  n \cr   k \cr}  \right\}$ as
the number  the number of ways to partition a set of n objects into k non-empty subsets

The decision will be taken when
$$
\left[ {x_{\,1}  \le x_{\,2}  \le  \cdots  \le x_{\,m - 1}  < x_{\,m} } \right]
$$
or any permutation of it.
Fixing the value of $x_m$, then the volume of such region will evidently be $x_m^{m-1}$, so that
the total volume of such a pyramid is
$$
V = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,r} {k^{\,m - 1} } 
$$
The m-tuples in which $x_m$ is strictly higher than the other components are of course
different (non-overlapping) with those in which the highest component is $x_1$ or $x_2$ and so on.
Therefore we have $m$ of such regions.

Now we have the basic elements to solve your question.

In your particular case, $m=3$ and $r=5$, the probability that a decision be taken is
$$
P_{decision}  = {{3\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,5} {k^{\,2} } } \over {6^{\,3} }} = {{165} \over {216}} = {{55} \over {72}}
$$

Comment: A decision can be made when the two lesser values are equal: $0\le x_1\le x_2 < x_3 \le r$

Comment: @DanielMathias: you are right: thanks for signalling!. I amended the answer

Answer (score 0):

The probability that a round ends without desicion is
$$
\underbrace{3\left(\frac16\right)^2\left(\frac56+\frac46+\frac36+\frac26+\frac16\right)}_{\frac{15}{72}}+
\underbrace{6\left(\frac16\right)^3}_{\frac{2}{72}}=\frac{17}{72}. 
$$
Here the first summand stands for two equal scores with a value larger than the third one. The factor $3$ stands for the number of ways to choose one person from three people. The values $\frac56,\frac46,\frac36,\frac26,\frac16$ in the parentheses are the probabilities of the third score to be less than  $6,5,4,3,2$, respectively. The second summand stands for the case with three equal scores.

Thus, the answer to the first question is
$$p_1=\left (\frac{17}{72}\right)^n .$$

To answer the second question recall that probability to get all three score equal is $\frac{15}2$ times less than to get only two equal scores. Therefore 
$$
p_2=1-\left (\frac{15}{17}\right)^{n-1}.$$

Comment: See the answer I linked in comment above. The probability that a round ends without a decision is $\frac{17}{72}$

Comment: @DanielMathias  Thank you for catching this. Indeed I did not notice the requirement that two scores have to be higher than the third one. Now my result agrees with yours.